# disable download_manager if user is on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this code that is enabling a download manager when user is from pc, what i need is to disable this function if user is on mobile ...

```
if ($('#download-manager').length) {
       var download_manager = $.cookie('download_manager') !== '0' ? true : false;
        if (!download_manager) {
            $('#download-manager-checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
        }
        $('#download-manager-checkbox').click(function() {
            var download_manager = $('#download-manager-checkbox').is(':checked') ? true : false;
            var status = download_manager ? '1' : '0';
            $.cookie('download_manager', status, {path: '/', expires: 365});

        });
    }
```

i tried with

```
if (screen.width <= 800) {
 delete download_manager;
  }
```

but didnt work ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot delete local variable in JavaScript. But having this

```
if (screen.width <= 800) {
  download_manager = false;
}
```

will do it for the code you've provided.

Or

```
if (screen.width <= 800) {
  download_manager = undefined;
}
```